# Problem with active record and the before_save filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code in my model, but something is not working as I expected.

```
   before_save :destroy_image?, :no_spaces_in_telephone

   def no_spaces_in_telephone
     self.phone.gsub! /\s+/, 'XXX'
     ABLog "Telefono", self.phone
   end

   def ABLog tag, string
     logger.info "\n\n#### #{tag} : \n " + string.to_s + "\n\n"
   end
```

The Log prints the phone with "XXX" in place of white spaces, but my record does not get updated, and the phone remains the same, with all the withes paces in their place.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you still need to equate the gsub return to self.phone, right? self.phone = self.phone.gsub!()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def no_spaces_in_telephone
     self.phone = self.phone.gsub /\s+/, 'XXX'
     ABLog "Telefono", self.phone
end
```

This is because self.phone= is a method.

Comment: Well, every accessor is a method. But in this case, you need to make Active Record aware of changes, which is a side-effect of setting an attribute. It does not notify if an attribute changes in-place but does not change its identity.